# How do I hide the tooltip 'title' when using a lightbox plugin

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am using [this lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox)  and I wanted to know how I can hide the tooltip with the `title` attribute that displays when I hover links to lightbox images.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with this plugin, your have to change its code a little.

Modifying `jquery.lightbox-0.5.js`, change

```
// in line 77:
objClicked.getAttribute('title')
// replace by:
objClicked.getAttribute('data-lightboxtitle')
```

*and*

```
// in line 81:
jQueryMatchedObj[i].getAttribute('title')
// replace by:
jQueryMatchedObj[i].getAttribute('data-lightboxtitle')
```

Then in your HTML, just replace the `title` attributes in your `a` with the `data-lightboxtitle`, like so (your code may differ a little, depending on how you use the plugin):

```
<a href="..." data-lightboxtitle="Here is your title" rel="lightbox"><img src="..." alt="..." /></a>
```

**Background:** By convention, browsers show a tooltip of your title attribute on mouseover if you have set one. Your plugin normally needs that to display the text in your lightbox, so you have no other chance than changing the plugin's behaviour.

**General advice:** You have a lot of downvotes on your question. Next time, try to be a bit more specific in your explanation and provide some code or your own attempts to deal with the problem ;)

Comment: Could you then please click on "accept" for this answer? That's how SO works ;)

Comment: Where it the "accept" button? I clicked "yes" on the question "was this post useful to you?" Hope that helps. Thanks again.

Comment: There's a little "tick" under the voting buttons of each _answer_ (like so: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png). That's called "accepting" an answer. It is also described in the _FAQ_ and _About_ sections of Stackoverflow (linked in the header).

Answer (score 0):

With the html supplied below, use this...

```
$("#gallery a").removeAttr("title");
```

If that doesn't work then we'll need to see your markup, as that works with the example gallery found at the page you linked.

Comment: $('...').removeAttr('title'); - I have tried this, however, it also removed the title whenever I clicked on the image. Thanks.

Comment: If you can make a working example in jsfiddle with just a couple of images then that will be better than masses of html.  We just need something short that demonstrates the problem, and then we can fix it.

Comment: I've modified the code to suit.  Just make sure you paste it *after* the lightbox initialisation.

Comment: I'm trying it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Archer: This won't work. Looking at the plugin code, I found out that the title attribute is evaluated "live" on each click. If it's empty (no matter whether before or after init), it won't display in the lightbox. See my answer below.